# gitpython - checking if branch is not merged with repo object?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, gitpython

I need to check if branch I'm interested is merged to another branch.

With `gitpython`, I can use its git command object like:

```
import git
g = git.Git('/path/to/git/repo')
g.branch("--no-merged", "master")
Out[273]: u'* new\n  test'
```

So it outputs correct branches, but format it returns is kind of not really good. Now I need to parse string and find the branch I'm interested.

I was thinking if the same can be accomplished using:

```
repo = git.Repo('/path/to/git/repo')
# Check branches using `repo` object as starting point?
```

With `repo` object, there are many useful methods that can retrieve useful information which is already parsed into objects, but I did not find how to do same thing with `repo` object (if it is possible at all?).

Answer (score 0):

I guess a merged branch is 0 commits ahead on the other (`master`) branch.

```py
from git import Repo
branch_name = 'is-this-branch-merged'    
repo = Repo('.')
commits_ahead = repo.iter_commits('origin/master..%s' % branch_name)
commits_ahead_count = sum(1 for c in commits_ahead)
is_merged = (commits_ahead_count == 0)
```

Would love to know of a better version where you can find all 'already merged' branches easily.

Comment: I used `repo.git.branch('--merged')` and parsed the out string.